# how to initialize array using for loop in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I've already created a code but when I'm going to display it i only displays the last number that I entered. Please help me.

```
@echo off
set /a count = 0
set /p process= How many process: 

:BT
echo BT
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%process%) DO (
    set /p bt [%%A]=
    IF %%A == %process% goto AT
)

:AT
echo AT
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%process%) DO (
   set /a count = %%A
   set /p at[count]=

   IF %%A == %process% goto TABLE
)

:TABLE
echo                       TABLE

echo PROCESS      AT                    BT
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%process%) DO (
    set /a count = %count%+1

    echo  P%%A         %at[count]%   

    IF %%A == %process% goto AWT
)

:AWT

pause
```

Comment: Read about `delayed expansion` as this is a FAQ that is asked regularly.

Comment: And also avoid spaces in variable names and also before and after equal signs

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off
set /p process= How many process: 
:BT

echo BT

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%process%) DO (
 set /p bt[%%A]=
)

:AT

echo AT

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%process%) DO (
 set /p at[%%A]=
)

:TABLE
echo                       TABLE

echo PROCESS      AT                    BT
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%process%) DO (
CALL echo  P%%A         %%at[%%A]%%   %%bt[%%A]%%
)

:AWT

pause

GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a fixed version.

Notes: `count` is not necessary. `%%A` contains the index 1..`%process%`.

spaces on **each** side of the `=` in a string-assignment (such as a `set /p`) are significant, so the space between the `bt` and `[` is removed.

Batch simply charges on through the lines of the program until it encounters `goto`, `call` or `exit`. The tests fo end-of-loop are thus not required - once the `for` loop ends, batch simply passes onto the next instruction line.

`at[count]` for instance is a variable name, same as `whatever`. `at[%count%]` means at[1]..at[??] depending on the value in `count`- but only **outside** of a "block" (parenthesised series of lines). **Within** a block, `at[%count%]` means `at[??]` where `??` is the value of `count` at the time the `for` statement was encountered. Thie may even be *nothingatall - an empty string* (ie `at[]`, which is a valid variablename.)

The `call echo` method uses a parsing trick to first substitute for `%%A` (the loop-control or `metavariable`) then `echo` `%at[2]%`. Some people don't like using this method - it's slower than the "as-designed" methods and under rare esoteric conditions may not yield the correct result. There are two "official" methods of accessing the **run-time** or **current** value of a variable within a loop - `setlocal` and using a subroutine call - both of which are extensively documented on SO.